# (Applescript) Get value from excel, find and replace in pages

Tags: applescript

First attempt at applescript. Have 2 open files, excel and pages.
Want to get a string from a cell in excel, and find&replace a placeholder in pages with this value.
while the code returns value from excel, it has no effect on the pages document. What am I doing wrong?

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    set name1 to string value of cell ("B7")
end tell

return name1

tell application "Pages" to tell untitled
    set every word whose contents is "name_placeholder" to name1
end tell
```

Comment: Well, with `return name1` the **Pages** `tell` _block_ is not even executed.  That said, it also is not properly formed. Also have look at https://iworkautomation.com/pages/ for some good background on using **AppleScript** in **Pages**.

Comment: Thanks! And great recommendation, worked from an example there.